# Authentication using Database Logins

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm somewhat new to ASP.NET MVC and I hoped you can help me with authentication for my app.

I have a MVC application that needs to be authenticated using SQL Server Log Ins. This means I have to create roles and users in SQL Server, and all security permissions are managed at Database level. Roles, users, and permissions aren't constant and we should be able to manage them.

Any suggestion? Is there anyway to override default behaviors of Identity to achieve this goal? What do you think is the best way to implement this need? Should I Use AD or DB Logins are fine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this an intranet or internet application? AD is nice when your clients are in the domain

Comment: It's an Intranet application. But does AD fulfill my demands? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You could use AD to tie back to the DB so you wont need to setup a seperate authentication mechanism. Use windows

Comment: Then can I manage roles and users from my application?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AD neither. Can I manage access to tables and actions from AD?

Comment: AD can manage the authentication. You can create roles in your DB and add windows group or users to those roles. Using windows auth you wont need to implement an authentication mechanism. If you dont have an AD server then i dont know if Id go fown that route.

Comment: Thanks for your attention Josh. We'd have an AD server, but what my manager is asking me is some management pages within application. So the administrator users should be able to manage roles and users. I guess I have to use AD APIs for that, which sounds painful?

Comment: In overall what do you suggest? Management capabilities from AD itself?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my working experience with diverse login mechanisms, I would like to suggest you the following route

1. Choose AD as your identity provider[IDP]
2. Register your application as an Relying Party [RP]
3. Get the federation metadata from AD to set up your application
4. In case you have your AD Server with ADFS 3.0, refer this [link](https://dsaravanan.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/configuring-ad-fs-3-0-in-windows-server-2012-r2/) for a sample
5. In case of going through the OWIN Federation Middleware, it should be very easy for you with little development effort as given in this [link](http://leastprivilege.com/2014/02/21/test-driving-the-ws-federation-authentication-middleware-for-katana/)

With ASP.Net MVC5 & Owin this task of yours should be a piece of cake

For Azure AD based samples, refer [here](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WSFederation-DotNet) or for first hand information, read [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/07/30/securing-a-web-api-with-windows-server-2012-r2-adfs-and-katana/) article

Comment: Thanks Saravanan, Can I achieve the same task with Identity 1? I'm kind of more familiar with the first version.

Comment: did you mean using the ASP.Net Identity

Comment: Yes, I meant using an integrated security framework that manages authentication and authorization at program and database level. But as far as I got it, using stored procedure is my best option, they I can handle exception in the app... .